# How to make integral substitution from 3d k-space to 1d energy domain with non-trivial dispersion relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, integration

In solid state phyics, one often encounters a subsitution from the 3d k space to a 1d integral via the standard dispersion relation $E= \vec{k}^2/2m$ via

\begin{align}
\int d\vec{k} Z(\vec{k}) = \int_0^\infty dE \mathcal{D}(E)
\end{align}

where we have the two different density of states $Z$ and $\mathcal{D}$. This is mainly solved by considering $d\vec{k} Z(\vec{k}) = dE \mathcal{D}(E)$ where we use $d\vec{k}=4\pi k^2 dk$ and $\frac{dE}{dk}=k/m$ and then use that there is (luckily) a mapping from $k=|\vec{k}|$ to $E$. I never really questioned this although this method we used is not mathmatically rigorous especially if one encounters another type of dispersion.

In my case, the dispersion is given by $E=\cos(k_x)+\cos(k_y)$ and the procedure above fails because the dispersion is not rotationally symmetric. As the subsitution $(k_x,k_y) \to E$ is not bijective, I fail to find a density of states $\mathcal{D}(E)$.

I am asking for a mathematically rigorous proof of the case for the symmetric dispersion, so mainly non-bijective subsitution which can also be applied to the non-rotationally symmetric dispersion.